# django DecimalField and scientific notation when displayed

Tags: django, django-admin

How to display the DecimalField without the E (scientific) notation in the django admin?

Here is my field:

```
models.DecimalField(max_digits=12, decimal_places=8, null=True)
```

I see in the admin:

```
0E-8.00000000  # on the table
0E-8           # in the form
```

Looking at this ticket https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/19220, I thought it was fixed but I have the issue so I am not sure what is happening...